# ftp listing and download file in current date

Tags: php, shell, ftp

I have a case,
I have a remote server that contains so many generated transaction files (.txt) from 2015 until now. I must download it everyday **real time**. For now, i use PHP to download it all, but the method i think is not effectifely. First, I list all files, and then I read the component of the files such as the date modified, but this method is annoying. Make my program run slowly and take a very much time.

This is my code (**I've used PHP Yii2**),

```
public function actionDownloadfile(){
    $contents=Yii::$app->ftpFs->listContents('/backup', ['timestamp','path','basename']); --> Much time needed while executing this line
    var_dump($contents);
    foreach ($contents as $value) {
        if (date('Y-m-d',$value['timestamp']) == date('Y-m-d')){
            echo "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] : Downloading file ".$value['basename']."\n";
            $isi = Yii::$app->ftpFs->read($value['path']);
            $dirOut = Yii::$app->params['out'];
            $fileoutgoing = $dirOut."/".$value['basename'];
            $file = fopen($fileoutgoing,"w");
            fwrite($file,$isi);
        }
    }
}
```

i have a question,
Is that possible to list and download some files in ftp server just only on this current date without listing them all first?

Any solution either using PHP or Shell Script is OK.

Thank you so much (y)

Comment: no, you need to know which files to pull, there is no ftp_fget_by_date() function.

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried and which part of your solution is not giving you the desired results. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: @sparkplug

I have a case,
I have a remote server that contains so many generated transaction files (.txt) from 2015 until now. I must download it everyday **real time**. For now, i use PHP to download it all, but the method i think is not effectifely. First, I list all files, and then I read the component of the files such as the date modified, but this method is annoying. Make my program run slowly and take a very much time.  

i have a question,
Is that possible to list and download some files in ftp server just only on this current date without listing them all first?

Thank you

Comment: No there no better way than, what you are doing already. Unless you are doing it wrong or ineffectively. But we cannot tell, unless you show us some code!

Comment: OK, code was posted. Thanks for the correction, i'm sorry :D

Comment: I do not know Yii2, but the code looks ok. I do not think there's any way to improve it, if FTP is the only interface you have.

Comment: is that any solution using shell script or something? Thanks before.

Comment: Sure, but that's a different question. Your question is about FTP. If you have other interfaces you can use to access the server, you have to specify that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ah, the bad news -> FTP is the only way to access that server, sad.